# Sharepoint Lists assign task to same multiple users

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, tasks, office

I have been tasked to create some sort of digital document. In summary, our company will release safety bulletins that all employees need to read and confirm that they have read them.
I would ideally like to use sharepoint lists to document this.
I would need it that, all managers can add this bulletin as a task and assign it to all employees and then each employee can then confirm they have read it.

I have tried the excel approach but I can't lock individual rows to users unless in the desktop app which isn't ideal.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

HAve you thought about a workflow? You can set the workflow to assign a task/user. How many users are you talking about? An alert will notify your users but does not always allow the user to respond unless it is customized. I suggest a workflow ..

Comment: Hi Puma. Thanks for your reply. There is roughly 45 - 50 users. I'm not familiar with workflows. Would this keep a record of what documents each user has signed for?

Answer (score 0):

A workflow would allow you to share the document and then the users can respond with a review through the task which is stored in a task list.